# pandas dataframe columns for each month of year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file with employee information. There are multiple records for an employee describing his monthly information. I want to create a consolidated dataframe where there are columns for each month and the number of leave days availed for each month is stored in the appropriate column
[image: sample of data]

```
   Emp. Code Month Year  leave Days
     1        2-2022         10
     2        3-2022         15
     1        3-2022         20
     2        2-2022         2
     1        4-2022         3
     1        5-2022         2
     2        6-2022         4
```

expected output

```
    empcode     leavedays-Feb leavedays-march leavedays-april 
     1             10             15               3             
     2             2              15               nil
```

Comment: Please provide your dataset as text - not as image. Refer [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables). Or you can `print(df)` and paste output.

Comment: Also, please provide your expected output dataframe in tabular format.

Comment: Emp. Code Month Year  Field Days  Non Call Days  Leave Days  Holidays  \
0          831556    02-2022        23.0            0.0           1         0   
1          831639    02-2022        22.0            0.0           1         0   
2          831714    02-2022        22.0            0.0           2         0   
4          830497    02-2022        18.0            0.0           5         0   
5          831244    02-2022        24.0            0.0           0         0   
...           ...        ...         ...            ...         ...       ...   

[4104 rows x 11 columns]

Comment: Please edit the question and add the dataset there.

Comment: Your data is split in multiple rows. It hard to interpret. Use `pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)` before printing data so that one row is in one column and paste again. A good formatted question helps to understand it and increases your chances of getting an answer.